# heroku and namecheap example.com url (redirecting from www.example.com to just example.com)

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a webpage example.com that I have set up fine using Heroku.  Right now, in my domain settings on Heroku, I have:

```
Domain Name                    DNS Target

example.com       example.herokuapp.com


www.example.com   example.herokuapp.com
```

In Namecheap I have:

```
Type         Host            Value                TTL          
CNAME       www  example.herokuapp.com.  30 min

URL Redirect Record @  http://www.example.com Unmasked
```

What is happening is that if I type example.com, it redirects to www.example.com.  What I would like is for both example.com and www.example.com to redirect to just example.com.

Not sure how to do that (new to heroku DNS).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't do that with Namecheap since they won't support you using example.herokuapp.com on the Apex record. If you want to be accessible on an URL like example.com you'd need to move your DNS to a provider that supports it like PointDNS, DNSimple, CloudFlare etc. These providers have implemented a technique which lets you use a CNAME on the apex record.